# Adding text using OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have written an android app which allows me to see the picture from my phones camera on the real time. What I want to do now is to add some text to the screen, so that it could be seen over the picture from the camera. I wonder, if I could use OpenCV for these purposes. However, I have read several tutorials, but i still do not understand how to do it. Could someone help me or just give an advice, how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you already integrated the openCV library into your application?

Comment: @timegalore Yes, i did.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Core.putText() : http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#putText(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.lang.String,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20int,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar)

(though it's quite limited, hershey font only, limited ascii subset, etc)

Comment: Thank you! And could you please tell me how to get the pictures fro the video? I found smth like this, but i am not sure, it is the correct way of doing this.  mCamera = new VideoCapture(CAMERA_ID);
    while (mCamera != null){
     boolean grabbed = mCamera.grab();
     if(grabbed){
      mCamera.retrieve(mCurrentFrame, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGB);
      
      
     }